# Does recovering from a different Windows disk affect your license?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot

My laptop came with pre-installed Windows 7 and I do not have a recovery DVD nor a Windows installation disk.

On boot the laptop says that BCD is missing. To recover I'd normally need a Windows installation disk. Does downloading a trial edition of Windows 8 and recovering affect my license ?

Comment: You can't use your mistake to "upgrade".  Besides you probably DON'T want win8 anyway.   Take a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft

Comment: There may also be a recovery partition on your hard drive.

Comment: Yes there is a recovery partition. But it too says that boot partition missing. Is there a solution ? Besides I don't want to upgrade. I just want to use bcdedit to edit the BCD.

Comment: Yes; It matters;  Why use Windows 8 when you can download and burn an Windows 7 .iso?  Its even a Superuser question.

Comment: Yeah okay. I just picked up Windows 8 because if I try to recover with some lower version of Windows it doesn't work. It has to be the same or a higher version.

Comment: The repair features, like for example `startup repair`, on Windows installation discs do not affect your existing installation's license. As @Ramhound has indicated there are official sources you can download Windows 7 isos from if you'd prefer it.

Comment: The problem with using Windows 8 is that the WinRE version is different.  Its not entirely a problem with 8.1 because the tools are more or less the same.

Comment: So does that mean I can use Windows 7 to recover without affecting my license? By recover I mean using the bootrec.exe to restore my BCD.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use bcdedit. It would be to complex.

As you want to use a Windows 8 trial version for recovering BCD

you can use bcdboot.exe to [repair/fix Windows BCD file](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).

Rewriting boot related files should not affect license.